# Pointing a project into two SVN repositories

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have a situation in which my Java project contains resources from a different project. 
Say my project contains Java code and some resource files for read only. The resource files are built/used and maintained by a different team. I want to be able to check them out within my project (from Eclipse). So I was looking at how can I make my resource directory points to an SVN repository different from the rest the of my project.

I am not sure if this is possible, but if anyone knows away around it please let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is called an [SVN external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html)

So, if you have a project that looks like this:

```
project
|
|-- folder1
|
|-- folder2
|
|-- resources
```

Then what you should do is to set the `svn:externals` property:

```
svn propset svn:externals 'resources http://svn.url.for.resources'
```

Using this approach, when you checkout the project `project`, SVN will automatically checkout the `resources` folder from the SVN repo you specified in the `svn:externals` property.